# Backbone.js fetch() is not changing URL

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have this code in Backbone.js where I am trying to create dynamically a URL and call a function from the controller which returns a JSON data.
For some reason when doing the fetch() method at the end the URL in my browser does not change.
I have put a console.log in my getdata() function just to see if the call is happening, and it does. Also i have tried to console.log the new build URL with the parameter at the end, and also this is build successfully.
 Any ideas why the URL in not changing in the browser?

Thank you

```
getUrl: function(celebname){ 
        var urlstr = "http://localhost/Codeigniter/index.php/testcontroller/getdatabasedata?searchvalue="+celebname; 
        return urlstr; 
        },

        events: {
            "click #submitbtn" : "getdata",

          },
          getdata: function (event) { 
            var celebname = $('#celebname').val(); 
            this.model.url = this.getUrl(celebname);
            this.model.fetch();
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone will always try to use the collection url, so if you want to `fetch` or `save` you should explicitly save the model with a new url.

Try overriding the url in the model like so:

```
var newUrl = this.getUrl(celebname);
this.model.save({}, { url: newUrl});
```

Instead of just setting `this.model.url = this.getUrl(celebname);`

Comment: I understand. I get this error: Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

Comment: Now I just get POST (my URL where the data should go)  500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: does your model have a url property set on it?

Comment: I have just set it now, and I dont get the Uncaught Error regarding the URL, just the POST error. In the controller I have a function that checks if: $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') or
$this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'GET') and gets the data or posts it.

Comment: sounds like you're hitting the url now but the request isn't being handled properly. it's pretty hard to know unless you get the specific reason for the 500 error

Comment: I would suggest debugging the issue on the server side and trying to find where the 500 is coming from. if you cannot solve this yourself, you can post a new question! it's better to keep these threads about one thing at a time, and it seems like the URL specific thing has been solved

Comment: I will try to figur it out. Does it matter what data I am trying to send, and what the function is expecting maybe.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help